# Debian file's permissions for secondary's group of user

Tags: permissions, filesystems, users, non-root-user

I am installing a proftpd server on a debian dedicated server,
In order to be able to update some website files in this folder :
`/var/www/website`

I have added a new user : my-ftp-user
This user's root is `/var/www/website`, but the owner HAS TO be apache2 (www-data).

So I changed the user's groups :

```
usermod -a -G ftpuser my-ftp-user
usermod -a -G www-data my-ftp-user
```

The permissions of folder `/var/www/website` are currently 755.
The subfolders are also in 755 mode, but the subfiles are in 644 mode.

If I am right, my-ftp-user should now be able to add, edit, remove files in `/var/www/website`, am I not ?

```
$ su my-ftp-user

$ cd /var/www/website

$ ls -la

drwxr-xr-x  5 www-data www-data  4096 juil. 30 13:47 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root   www-data  4096 juil. 30 13:36 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   418 juil. 28 18:39 index.php

$ cat index.php // WORKS

$ touch test.txt // DOESN'T WORK : permission denied, why ?
```

Comment: What is the group that owns `/var/www/website` ?

Comment: The apache group www-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for `EPERM` (the permission denied error ) is here:

```
drwxr-xr-x  5 www-data www-data  4096 juil. 30 13:47 .
```

The directory where you are trying to create a file (in other words change contents of the directory-file) is writeable only for user `www-data`, which you are not.

Either mark the directory as writeable for the group, change the user to `www-data` (or change the owner to my-ftp-user) or (probably the best solution) use extended ACLs with the `setfacl` command.

Comment: Okay, so I guess I have to change the rights to 774 or something ?

Is there any way to make a difference between folders and files with chmod ?

For instance, to change to permissions to 775 for folders and 664 for files ?

Comment: Files usually don't have the execution bit set - that is intended for executables only. For directories the executable bit controls whether it is possible to traverse that directory - so it is usually a good idea to set it whenever the read bit is set.

Comment: As for changing it to `0775`: using extended ACLs (if your file system supports them) is better security-wise, since it limits the number of possible writers. You may need to tweak the *default* ACLs as well, if you need to create directory hierarchies with such user, though.

Comment: I am not a system admin at the beginning, just a developer, and I do not know anything about the system, so I guess I would not try to manage extended ACL, even if it seems to be a very good solution ;
I only had a small need, there will not be more users hierarchies at the moment, so I think "chmod" is enough for my needs.
And as there are really few accesses to this private server, I don't feel really concerned about security anyway, I hope I am not wrong...

Comment: @Flo-Schield-Bobby So that explains. group needs also `rwx` on `website` directory.  You can grant access to the ftp user using `setfacl -m u:my-ftp-user:rwx /var/www/website`  No need for other changes